# Second definition of bounded function.

Tags: functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $S =\left\{\ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | \exists \in > 0  : \forall δ > 0, |x-y| < δ  \implies  |f(x)-f(y)| < \in \right\}$ then

1. $S = \left\{f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | f\text{ is continuous}\right\}$
2. $S = \left\{f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | f\text{ is uniformly continuous}\right\}$
3. $S = \left\{f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | f\text{ is bounded}\right\}$
4. $S = \left\{f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | f\text{ is constant}\right\}$

My Attempt : Let $y = a$ (constant) and $x \in \Bbb R$ then $|f(x)-f(a)| < \in$ $\implies |f(x)|-|f(a)| < \in$ $\implies |f(x)| < \in + |f(a)|$ $\implies$ f is bounded. Am I right ? How to discard other options.
I'm confusing with the fact that if $y = a$ (constant) then $f(a)$ finitely exist ( why ? ).

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is right but I would have worded it differently.

We are going to prove that every function in $S$ is bounded and that every bounded function is in $S$. Thus the answer is 3.

Let $f\in S$, then There exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$, $$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\implies\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\epsilon$$
Since it is true for every $\delta$, we could take it as large as we want. If we fix the value of $y=a\in\Bbb R$, then we must have that for every $x\in\Bbb R$
$$\lvert f(x)-f(a)\rvert<\epsilon$$
Since $y=a$ is part of the domain of the function, then $f(a)$ exist.
If we remove absolute value, we have
$$-\epsilon <f(x)-f(a)<\epsilon$$
Adding $f(a)$ to every term, we gave
$$f(a)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon$$
Thus $f$ is bounded.

Conversly, if $f$ is bounded, then there exist $M, N\in\Bbb R$ such that 
$$N\leq f(x)\leq M\qquad\forall x\in\Bbb R$$
Let take $$\epsilon=2\times \max(|M|, |N|)+1$$
Then for every $x, y\in\Bbb R$, we have
$$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\leq \lvert f(x)\rvert+\lvert f(y)\rvert\leq \max(|M|, |N|)+\max(|M|, |N|)=2\times\max(|M|, |N|)<\epsilon$$
Then $f\in S$.

Conclusion, your definition of $S$ is equivalent to 3.

For the other options, if $f$ is constant, it is bounded, so it is include in case 3.

For continuous or uniformly continuous function, we only need an example of function that doesn't respect the condition.

Let $f(x)=x$. Obviously, $f$ is uniformly continuous, but does it satisfy the condition to be in $S$?

Let $\epsilon>0$, take $y=x+\epsilon+1$. There exist a $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta$, so $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert$ must be smaller than $\epsilon$. But
$$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert=\lvert x-(x+\epsilon+1)\rvert =\lvert-\epsilon-1\rvert=\epsilon+1>\epsilon$$

Conclusion, for $f(x)=x$, it is impossible to find the $\epsilon$ required by the definition of $S$. We found an uniformly continuous function not in $S$, Thus $S$ is not equivalent to 1 or 2.

Comment: I understood clearly what did you say. But I'm confusing, please see my attempt again.

Comment: Choose $a$ in the domain of $f$, then $f(a)$ exist and is finite.

Comment: But domain is $\Bbb R$ which is unbounded and take $f(x) = x$ which is unbounded on $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Baljeet yes $f(x)=x$ is unbounded. I use this function to show 1 and 2 are not the answer: a continuous function ia not necessairly in $S$.